# Yii2 DateTime model validation format issue

Tags: php, validation, datetime, model, yii2

Created a model with a dateTime field called 'until', the name is not important just that it is a date time.
Here is it's validation in the rules of the model.

```
['until', 'datetime', 'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'],
```

Later after I instantiate the model and update the field I get a validation error.

```
$model->until = '2017-10-15 14:30:04';
$eventRepeat->validate();
$errors = $model->errors;
```

$errors['until'][0] will then be 'The format of Until is invalid.'

I was not expecting this error.

Comment: This still happens if I change the format to:
'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

set the format to

> php:Y-m-d H:i:s

and used the formatter.

```
$model->until = Yii::$app
            ->formatter
            ->asDatetime(
                new DateTime('NOW + 2 weeks'),
                'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'
            );
```

Answer (score 6):

As in Yii2 Doc

> format: the date/time format that the value being validated should be
>   in. This can be a date time pattern as described in the ICU manual.
>   Alternatively this can be a string prefixed with `php:` representing a
>   format that can be recognized by the PHP Datetime class.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#date

try using

```
['until', 'datetime', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],
```

Comment: Thank you! That's helped me. I also added a use of the formatter. see below